# unable to make indexeddb work in android 4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexeddb, polyfills

i was devlopping an offline store using indexeddb it work very nice with android 4.4 sadnly when i tested it with a device < 4.4 it doesnt work 
i was serching in the net i fond that i must use a polyfill,i add this to my exixting project

```
    <script src="js/jquery.indexeddb.js"></script>
    <script src="js/IndexedDBShim.js"></script>
     <script src="js/IndexedDBShim.min.js"></script> 
     <script src="js/jquery.indexeddb.min.js"></script>
```

but nothing work and i had 2 error

Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 at file:///android_asset/www/js/IndexedDBShim.min.js:2
and 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined atfile:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.indexeddb.js:522
Can any one help me since im really blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like jQuery is not included. At the very top of the file, make sure to include the jQuery file and also add it to your application cache manifest (if you're using one, which I'm assuming you are since you're using indexedDB). You can get the jQuery files that you should include here: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: yes i have the jquery.js included but the errer exist :/ and i dont use any cache manifest,i have speed  2day and nothing work

Comment: i resolve the 2nd error it was just problem of classment i was calling jquery.js in the end